# APA Formatting - Changing Adjectives in a quote

Tags: formatting, quotes

Should I change "our" to "their" in this quote? If so, how?

As stated in their 2011 Annual Report, Siemens’ identity and corporate culture is defined by their vision to be a pioneer, which is based on their values of being responsible, excellent and innovative (Siemens, 2011). “Together with these values, our strategy and One Siemens framework, it also defines our business goals and specifies a clear direction for our development” (Siemens, 2011, p. 21).

Answer (score 4):

Knowing nothing about APA formatting, I would say that the material in quotes should stay quoted — use "our," since it's a direct quote which you immediately cite. I don't see a reason to change the actual quote, and your summary in the previous sentence uses "their" correctly in context.

There are contexts where you'd change *our* to [their] with the straight brackets, or use [sic] to indicate a mistake in the original quote, but this is fine as it stands.

Comment: I agree.  Keep the quote as it is.  Inside the quotes, you're in a separate world where "our" already means "their".